# Перенести на сайте картинки из временной папки в другую

Tags: файлы, php

```
if ($foto != '') {
    $uploadDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/template/img/uploads/'; //папка для хранения файлов
    $uploadDirMini = $uploadDir. 'mini/';
    $DirNew = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/template/img/ads/'; //папка для хранения файлов
    $DirMiniNew = $DirNew. 'mini/';
    $img = explode(':', $foto);
    foreach($img as $u) {
        if (rename($uploadDir.$u, $DirNew.$u)) {
            $res = 'true';
        } else {
            $res = 'false';
        }
    }
}
```

Вот такой код, но `$res = false`. Как я думаю, ошибка в обертке, но какой урл нужно писать в переменные, чтобы все работало, я не знаю. ((

Comment: @yazadjidima, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
$img = explode(':', $foto);
```

Я так понимаю, список файлов у вас через двоеточие оформлен в строку? Если да, то тогда проверьте доступы к папкам и файлам, кроме того, почему бы не воспользоваться `move_uploaded_file`? Но я вам настоятельно рекомендую сначала проверить `is_readable` и `is_file`, чтобы удостовериться, что вы не воздух гоняете.

Comment: В БД я храню названия картинок, загруженные ранее, потом получаю их название и добавляю до урла директории и просто переношу с одной папки в другую. Но тут проблема: как записать урл или как получить файл по-другому, move_uploaded_file - только для закаченных в форме, а тут я работаю со стракой названий картинок из БД.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ: перед rename добавить '@' -> @rename() - не будет предуприждений и файл переименуется, а false был из-за того, что explode() сделал две строки массива 'img.jpg' и '' и последняя строка не как имя файла, то и не могла перенести "ветер".